# Ngnix: setting up multiple websites with SSL/Docker

Tags: docker, nginx

**I need to set up a server that does multiple things:**

- Hosts a Grafana instance on docker (`3000` is the default port)
- Hosts a flask service for printing Grafana reports (the default Grafana printing sucks so I built a Selenium robot to grab the objects on the screen, create a PDF and download the results)
- Hosts a Docker App built with Wappler (Php-based app builder)

I'd like to use free certs (lets encrypt).

I'm new to docker and new to linux server administration. What's the best resource for learning how to set this up?

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/

Answer (score 0):

It's super easy to setup reverse proxies using the [Linuxserver LetsEncrypt container](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/letsencrypt/) (It's an Nginx container that auto-manages free certs). The initial setup if you're completely new to docker might seem a little intimidating, but it's easier than it looks, and once you get the hang of it, it's cake.

Other than that, you just need to be sure to place all 3 in the same docker network so they can talk to each other, and (if you want) also expose those ports to the host during the `docker run` or `docker compose` code.

i.e. (pseudo code):

`docker run -d --name grafana -p 3000:3000 grafana/grafana`

Comment: Thanks for sending this. Will definitely check it out! (Also thanks for fixing my question formatting...I always search stack overflow but this was the first time I have ever posted a question.)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who ends up finding this via a search, I ended up using Traefik for routing/SSL setup. The best article I found on how to set this up is [here.](https://medium.com/@containeroo/traefik-2-0-docker-a-simple-step-by-step-guide-e0be0c17cfa5)

(Note many articles reference Traefik 1.7, however, they changed a lot between 1.7 and version 2. The article above uses Traefik 2.0)

Basically the way that Traefik works is it sees other docker containers that are in the same network and if the docker container contains specific labels set in the docker configuration, it will automatically generate LetsEncrypt SSL certs (see the [docs](https://docs.traefik.io/v2.1/https/acme/)) and will perform the routing to the docker container.